# Access Geoprocessing results in Flex Viewer (Enhanced) Search Widget

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

I have Robert Scheitlin's Enhanced Search Widget up and running successfully with my MapService using ArcGIS Server and Flex Viewer 2.3. I also have a geoprocessing service that returns a point layer as part of my map. This works great-- the points display properly and I am able to query them individually.  However, I would like the user to be able to select all or a subset of results and view the table in a DataGrid. I am fairly new to both ArcGIS Server and Flex (I have poked around the uncompiled code, but haven't gotten into it yet).

In order for the Search widget to work, the URL of the GP service endpoint is required.  This URL includes a unique JOBID.  The Geoprocessor Widget gets the JOBID, but I don't know how (or if it is possible) to pass that JOBID to the Search Widget XML file to build the URL dynamically as the JOBID changes with each instance of the map.

Essentially, all I'm trying to do is allow the user to interact with the point and attribute table a la ArcMap. Any ideas or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
-Erik